# I want to set the position of syncfusion:DropDownButtonAdv fixed on grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have Following Xaml in wpf Application.

I want the syncfusion:DropDownButtonAdv position fixed and it should not be moved from it's original position even after scrolling. It should look just upper side of Syncfusion:sfDataGrid.
I have used Panel.Zindex but its position can't be remain fixed.

I don't know how to fix this.
please help me with this.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid Background="Black">
                <StackPanel Background="Black">
                       <Stackpanel>
                             syncfusion:SfDataGrid Code
                       </Stackpanel> 

                       <Stackpanel>
                             Some Code
                       </Stackpanel> 
                 </Stackpanel> 

    <syncfusion:DropDownButtonAdv x:Name="dropdownButton" DropDirection="TopLeft" SizeMode="Normal" Panel.ZIndex="1000">
                    <syncfusion:DropDownMenuGroup>
                        <syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem HorizontalAlignment="Left" Header="Add\New" Command="{Binding DataContext.OnAddNew,ElementName=dropdownButton}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                            <syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="\Resources\MenuIcon.png"/>
                            </syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem.Icon>
                        </syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem>
                        <syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem HorizontalAlignment="Left" Header="Call">
                            <syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="\Resources\Call.png"/>
                            </syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem.Icon>
                        </syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem>
                        <syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem HorizontalAlignment="Left" Header="SMS">
                            <syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="\Resources\SMS.png"/>
                            </syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem.Icon>
                        </syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem>
                        <syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem HorizontalAlignment="Left" Header="Email">
                            <syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="\Resources\Email.png"/>
                            </syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem.Icon>
                        </syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem>
                        <syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem HorizontalAlignment="Left" Header="DPPO Exports"/>
                        <syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem HorizontalAlignment="Left" Header="BO Exports"/>
                        <syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem HorizontalAlignment="Left" Header="UCC Exports"/>
                        <syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem HorizontalAlignment="Left" Header="CKYC Exports"/>
                        <syncfusion:DropDownMenuItem HorizontalAlignment="Left" Header="DMAT Exports"/>
                    </syncfusion:DropDownMenuGroup>
                </syncfusion:DropDownButtonAdv>
                </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `Panel.ZIndex`?

Comment: Although If I removed  Panel.Zindex its working the same. syncfusion:DropDownButtonAdv showed on grid.    I want that syncfusion:DropDownButtonAdv should be look just upper on the grid, so I kept the button outside of stackpanel which consist entire sfDataGrid code.  I want button should not be moved from original position when I scroll the grid. so I added panel.zIndex but its not working. Is there any solution for this. Thank You.